# Remove cell from customized UICollectionView like Pinterest

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, pinterest

I have a UICollectionView customized like Pinterest. I archived this following [this Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2). I did everything exactly like in here and it works perfect. The problem appears while trying to remove a cell from the collection view. I use this function to make the removal:

```
extension PintViewController:FavouriteOffersDelegate{

func collectionViewCellDidTapHeart(_ sender: PntCollectionViewCell) {
    guard let indexTapped = collectionView.indexPath(for: sender) else {
        return
    }
    let id:Int = generalsOffersArray[indexTapped.row].id
    print(indexTapped.item)
    generalsOffersArray.remove(at: indexTapped.item)
    collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexTapped])

    }
}
```

I understand the problem must be at the library I use but I'm new at Swift and can not clearly understand what I should modify or remove to make it work. When this code is executed the error I get I the console is:

> 2017-10-18 17:25:20.637123+0200 RemoveItemsPinterest[1017:432532] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3694.4.18/UICollectionViewData.m:435
>   2017-10-18 17:25:20.638356+0200 RemoveItemsPinterest[1017:432532] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 12}'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1833bfd38 0x1828d4528 0x1833bfc0c 0x183d4ec24 0x18c82b834 0x18c82ab8c 0x18d2964ac 0x18d2412b8 0x18d241218 0x18d241148 0x18c82a1cc 0x18c7cd000 0x18739d0b4 0x1873a1194 0x18730ff24 0x187336340 0x18ca33744 0x18d112718 0x18d10b574 0x183368358 0x1833682d8 0x183367b60 0x183365738 0x1832862d8 0x185117f84 0x18c833880 0x1000c8ee4 0x182daa56c)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The code for layout object :

```
class PinterestLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
var delegate:PinterestLayoutDelegate!

var numberOfColumns = 2
var cellPadding: CGFloat = 5.0

fileprivate var cache = [PinterestLayoutAttributes]()

fileprivate var contentHeight:CGFloat  = 0.0
fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
    let insets = collectionView!.contentInset
    return collectionView!.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
}

override class var layoutAttributesClass : AnyClass {
    return PinterestLayoutAttributes.self
}

override func prepare() {
    if cache.isEmpty {

        let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
        for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth )
        }
        var column = 0
        var yOffset = [CGFloat](repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)

        for item in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

            let width = columnWidth - cellPadding*2
            let photoHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath , withWidth:width)
            let annotationHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!, heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath: indexPath, withWidth: width)
            let height = cellPadding +  photoHeight + annotationHeight + cellPadding
            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

            let attributes = PinterestLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.photoHeight = photoHeight
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)

            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

            column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : column + 1
        }
    }
}

override var collectionViewContentSize : CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
    for attributes  in cache {
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect ) {
            layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }
    return layoutAttributes
}
}
```

Comment: Could you try to change generalsOffersArray.remove(at: indexTapped.item) to generalsOffersArray.remove(at: indexTapped.row) ?

Comment: Yeah I have tried this, they both return the same value, and still the same problem.

Comment: Than take a look at the count of generalsOffersArray after removing? The count of your array always have to be the same of the collectionView, if you delete rows with animation... If animation doesn't matter, just change collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexTapped]) to a tableView.reloadData()

Comment: This code allows you to delete a few cells and after that it just crashes with the same error again. I'm starting to think that propably it's the library I use that I should modify. I just have no idea how

Comment: Yes, but is the count of the array after the removal the same as the count of your tableView after the removal?

Comment: What layout object do you use? The error message tells you your layout object is returning wrong layout attributes.

Comment: If it is a bigger problem, I maybe can help you if you let me take a look at your code on GitHub, or BitBucket... Is that possible?

Comment: I've edited the question and added  the class for the layout object.

Comment: It looks like you fill "cache" only once. You should take a look at invalidateLayoutWithContext.